# link to edit another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 2 models with the following association.

goal.rb

```
has_one :progress
```

progress.rb

```
belongs_to :goal
```

In the goal index page, I have a link that suppose to edit the progress record for that particular goal, but I couldn't get it to find the correct record id of the progress record. My link_to code is as per below. It will pass the goal id instead of the correct progress id.

app/view/goals/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Progress', edit_progress_path(goal) %>
```

How should I go about this.

Thank you.

Cheers,
Azren

Comment: Which one of many progresses do you want to edit?

Comment: Basically a goal will have only 1 progress. So I would like edit the progress which has the same goal_id as the goal.id. If that make sense.

Comment: Then why the relationship is `has_many` and not `has_one`?

Comment: You are right. it should be has_one instead of has_many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't pass a `goal` object, but a `progress` object to the `edit_progress_path` method:

```
<%= link_to 'Progress', edit_progress_path(goal.progress) %>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm fond of using Rails "magic":

```
<%= link_to 'Progress', [:edit, goal.progress] %>
```

Comment: thanks, it works :-). Wondering which one will be the rails way of doing this? The above or this one?

Comment: Mine, of course! :-) Truth to be told, using `[:edit, goal.progress]` leads to calling `edit_progress_path`, but behind the scene. It's useful when you're constructing long scoped paths.